# Method expression is not of Function type

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpstorm, jslint

I have the following JavaScript file:

```
/*global $ */

function foo() {
    'use strict';
    var $tr = $('table tr'),
        $td = $tr.children('td');

    $td.html('Hello World');
}
```

In PHPStorm, `children` gets underlined with a weak warning. Mousing over it reveals this message:

> Method expression is not of Function type

This file is in the same directory as jquery.min.js (v. 1.11.0, if that matters).

How can I fix this?

Note that the above example is a minimalist example sufficient to reproduce the problem; it's not my actual code, but it will product the same result.

Comment: are you sure `$` is referring to jQuery? can you try `var $tr = jQuery('table tr')`

Comment: Okay, this is weird. Yes, I'm sure that's what it refers to in the sense that it definitely refers to jQuery when I run it. But making the change you suggested makes the warning go away in PHPStorm. Any thoughts on why that is?

Comment: I should point out that my real source code is part of an existing, deployed-in-the-wild project, so I would rather make the warning go away in PHPStorm than change all uses of `$` to `jQuery`. Thanks.

Comment: Not a PHP guy... http://www.bloglovin.com/viewer?post=2469106805&group=0&frame_type=a&blog=6519549&frame=1&click=0&user=0

Comment: it looks like some king of IDE configuration issue... also see http://www.bloglovin.com/viewer?post=2485639789&group=0&frame_type=a&blog=6519549&frame=1&click=0&user=0

Comment: The problem must be with PHP.  I recreated in jsfiddle and it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/h26tcmLj/

Comment: @JoaoCunha just to clarify, the problem isn't that the above code doesn't work. It works fine. It's the IDE warning that is the problem; the IDE has tons of these warnings, but they are wrong/useless. Also, to be clear, the code above is in a .js file, not a .php file.

Comment: Right... So it's probably what Arun said. The IDE must not know of the use of dollar in jQuery... Can you take off the dollar signs of the tr and td variables since it is just javaScript?

Comment: @JoaoCunha The variable names themselves don't matter; it turns out that I simply needed to include the uncompressed version of jQuery in my project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have my answer thanks to Arun P Johny. I needed to have jquery-1.11.1.js (the uncompressed version) somewhere in my project. I added it, and PHPStorm immediately resolved all jQuery-related warnings.

Comment: Now, 6 years later, we have jQuery 3.5.1 and PhpStorm has it in its cache `~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2/javascript/extLibs/http_ajax.googleapis.com_ajax_libs_jquery_3.5.1_jquery.js` is the uncompressed version and it shows this message by `$object.fadeOut(1000);`- any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to add jQuery as a library here:

Settings/Preferences dialog, click JavaScript under Languages and Frameworks, then click Libraries.

Comment: Actually, this didn't solve the problem at the time that this occurred. I'm not sure if it would solve the problem with the latest versions of PHPStorm.

Answer (score -3):

This is usually associated with phpstorm so either download and use the Jquery uncompressed version or use Jquery with CDN, it will be resolved.

Comment: I solved this question (with help from another user) and posted and accepted my own answer 4.5 years ago. Your answer adds nothing to that answer. And I know the problem is specific to PHPStorm; that’s why I mentioned PHPStorm in my question and my answer and used the PHPStorm tag.