# Unresolved function or method in module loaded in different <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, pycharm

PyCharm is reporting me `Unresolved function or method` in the following pattern:

```html
<script src="some-lib.js"></script>
<script>
  var foo = use_some_lib();
  foo.do.stuff();
</script>
```

`use_some_lib()` method that is part of `some-lib.js` is "Unresolved".

Is there any proper way or best practice to handle it? I found workarounds suggesting to append second code in second tag to the code of `some-lib.js`, but it does not seem to be an elegant solution.

Comment: Just a hunch: Is the library external? If so, download the library some-lib.js to your project and add it as an external library. I had [a similar problem with PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26540822/2057919), another IDE by the same people who make PyCharm (Jetbrains).

Comment: Is it working in the browser?

Comment: Does the code working fine in the browser and PyCharm is only reporting this issue? or is it not working in the browser as well.

Comment: Yes the code is working fine in browser, and library is loaded from CDN. It's only about PyCharm complaints.